# NRE with For Each

Tags: vb.net, foreach, nullreferenceexception

Well, I know about John Saunders' thread about NRE issues. I have read all threads I could find, but it didn't help me. I'm kinda stuck here.

```
For Each lum As Lumiere In autom.colLumiere
    s += If(lum.Checked, "1", "0") + ";"
Next
```

The first line throws NRE. Problem is it throws after minutes of processing. I used Instant Spy to check if something is Nothing, but autom and autom.colLumiere are not. Actually, when I check before and after NRE was thrown, the whole stuff is exactly the same.

I tried to put this just before the For Each, and as intended it doesn't show any MsgBox since nothing is null.

```
If autom Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("autom NRE")
ElseIf autom.colLumiere Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("colLumiere NRE")
ElseIf autom.colLumiere(1) Is Nothing ... Or autom.colLumiere(8) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox("lum NRE")
End If
```

Last thing is autom is not supposed to be changed outside this snippet, and actually it doesn't seem to be changed at all. No way it bugs, it is sorcery ;)

EDIT :

I have replaced the code with this instead :

```
For i = 1 To 8 Step 1
    s += If(autom.colLumiere(i).Checked, "1", "0") + ";"
Next
```

It seems to work (actually it didn't throw NRE after couple minutes of using, it's not 100% sure it works for ever). But even if it works great, I can't understand what was wrong with previous code.

Those For and For Each are not supposed to perform the same ?

Comment: As a guess: Did you initialize autom.colLumiere(0) ? Arrays and Lists are zero based in .NET.

Comment: List in vb.net is one based. Index zero is reserved. Anyway, code runs for couple minutes before it goes off.

Comment: Arty, i guess you need some reading about List(Of T). See the Item property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: autom.colLumiere(0) throws IndexOutOfRangeException. "Empty placeholder to adjust for 1-based array." is inside autom.colAutom(0)

Comment: What type of object is this ? Is this a third party object ?

Comment: My bad, it's not a List(Of T) but a Collection. I'll try with List(Of T) to avoid List(Of T)(0) being reserved, and i'll tell you if it works. Thanks anyway

Comment: The For Each seems to work properly with List(Of T) instead of Collection. Don't know really why, but after couple minutes, Collection(0) seems to be a problem with For Each. If you want to post an answer, i'll accept it. And if someone can explain me the issue, it would be nice !

Comment: As i can`t explain why the NRE is happening, i won`t post an answer.